# Does anyone know a surefire way of installing git on Solaris 9?

Tags: solaris, git

I tried the OpenCSW method but I am afraid that is only Solaris 10 and 11. git command just yields `command not found`. Surely someone out there has configured/used git on Solaris 9.

Comment: "The last update was Solaris 9 9/05" :-/ http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/overview/releases-jsp-140987.html

Comment: Surefire?  Compile from source, fixing all the problems you find along the way.  Solaris 9 is *old*.

Comment: Hi,I successfully installed git client from opencsw.org/packages/git on the following platforms: Solaris 10 x86-64 and on Solaris 9 with Sparc 64.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong about OpenCSW. I just missed adding the git executable to the path. This is still unsupported per their description but it seems to still work.

https://www.opencsw.org/packages/git/

Follow the steps listed here and then `git` should be located here:

> /opt/csw/libexec/git-core/git